# Insert from table with deafult value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Insert into table1 (login,code,domain, email,group)
Select user,null,default,mail,null
from table2
```

выдает `ошибку incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'`.
Подскажите где накосячил в синтаксисе.
Из другой таблицы хочу чтобы в столбец domain добавлялись значения по дефолту
в таблице table2 значение default указано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто убрать столбец из списка

```
Insert into table1 (login, code, email, group)
Select user, null, mail, null
from table2
```

Только default должен быть указан в целевой таблице (table1)